# Dasam Granth being offensive on Hindu Gods

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama, ganesha, sikhism

I came across a post about Dasam Granth saying the following:

I do not seek the blessings of Ganesh,
I do not worship Krishna or Vishnu.
I do not recognize them.
I am engrossed in the loving devotion of my Lord alone.
The Lord of Death, Akal, is my refuge and He saves me in all tribulations.

I also found some sources as follows:

https://www.sikhiwiki.org/index.php/Guru_Gobind_Singh_Ji_and_the_Dasam_Granth

https://www.sikhitothemax.org/shabad?id=8309

I know that Sikhs believe in Waheguru but isn't it offensive to hurt someone's sentiment by considering their Gods just as a human?

I understand that God can be formless as well as form. God knows that it's difficult to understand the formless and hence, God decided to perform leels in the form of Shri Ram or Shri Krishna so that we can get to know him. I was reading somewhere that Lord Ram and Lord Krishna were never born from the womb. Their appearance and disappearance were divine and were not like a human being.

I came across lines from Dasam Granth written by Sikh Guru which I thought were hurtful for people who believe in Shri Krishna or any other God and worship them.

What do you think about it?
Please help me to understand if I said something wrong. My apologies in advance.

Comment: Sikhs don't believe in personal gods or idols from what I understand their god is like Ishvara the basic concept of god. Which is more in tune with Abrahamic concepts. Note Ishvara isn't like an Abrahmic concept, but it is the basic idea of a supreme authority, not the Abrahamic god. While I don't see it as offensive since other Hindu Puranas have done something similar such as Vishnu Purana towards Shiva. So, it would be hypocritical to see it as offensive with all due respect. That being said Vishnu is supreme lol.

Comment: No. It is in the sense that it doesn't *invalidate* the existence of Gods. It just means that you don't want to use them or devote to them. This is essentially similar to the Buddhist concept - they agree there could be gods, but they tend to use a path that doesn't require the existence of gods through their own doctrines and some Hindu concepts too. Abrahamic ones tend to show superiority over others usually, but that isn't the case here. But if there is a *disrespect* to the part of others, then it is surely offensive. There is never one way superior to other.